# Is it possible to turn particles into points/point cloud?

Tags: particles, point-clouds

Now with the release of 3.1 and point clouds. I was wondering if it's possible to convert particles to point clouds and render them as point clouds. This seems like it would be much more efficient  than instancing spheres.

Answer (score -1):

I think this video is the answer to your question :)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MjM16FUMOKM&t=1205s

Comment: Hey there, we discourage links as answers here, since we're trying to build a long-term repository

Comment: This is very close. Only drawback is it doesn't use the particle info node for shaders.